# TCP/IP Drivers for QNX 4.2

Tags: drivers, tcpip

Does anyone have, or know where I can get my hands on TCP/IP Drivers for QNX 4.2

qnx.com wants ~ $400 for the drivers.. I'm hoping someone has written their own or knows of some good free ones.

Comment: got the unix like tag because qnx doesn't have it's own tag.

Comment: added a qnx tag.

Comment: that will help, I just started working with antiquated QNX 4.2 (circa 1995) thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ugh.. nevermind it was just impossible to find.

ftp://ftp.qnx.com/usr/free/qnx4/tcpip/